# Variations of difference-in-difference method

Tags: time-series, causality, difference-in-difference

I have data from a group of patients and for each patient I have two time series A and B (continuous quantity) sampled on a weekly basis. My hypothesis is that quantity B has a 1-week lagged effect on quantity A, causing A to drop with increasing B and I want to estimate this causal effect using the difference-in-difference method.

However, I don't think my problem fits the canonical setup for a difference-in-difference analysis since 1) I don't have a natural control and treatment group, but what I have done is match patients with similar characteristics to create synthetic control/treatment pairs to remove potentially unobserved confounders. Under this set up, first what I started with is

$A_{i,t} = \alpha_i + \kappa_t + \beta x_{
i,t} + \tau B_{i,t-1} + \epsilon_{i,t}$

where $\alpha_i$ represents time-invariant measure of patient heterogeneity in A, and $\kappa_t$ presents time trend across patients; $x_{i,t}$ is a factor that vary across both patient and time. Then what I did was a two-step differencing, across time (first difference) and between the matched pairs:

$\Delta_{x,y} \delta_t A = \beta \Delta_{x,y}\delta_t x + \tau \Delta_{x,y}\delta_t B + \Delta_{x,y}\delta_t \epsilon$

where $\alpha$ and $\kappa$ have dropped out because of the differencing. I then basically ran this regression at each time point $t$ for each matched pair.

I am however skeptical about this method as (1) the canonical DiD method requires the parallel treatment assumption, but in this case there is no well defined pre-treatment period and so there is no way to test this, and (2) serial correlation between weekly measurements of A and B.

I am wondering if there are variations of the DiD method that could be applied to such a problem, and if not what alternative solutions are there to estimate the causal effect (e.g. VAR/SVAR models with Granger causality?)

Comment: I’m confused about the relationship here. The quantity $A$ has a delayed effect on $B$? Isn’t $B$ your treatment?

Comment: @ThomasBilach Oops you're right, I made the correction accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The description of your problem does not generally match a difference-in-differences (DiD) design. Compared to the usual 2x2 setup, it lacks a the usual treatment / control group and pre- and post treatment definitions.

Based on your hypothesis, your model could be a lagged regression:

$$
A_t = \alpha + \beta B_{t-1} + \sum_{j=1}^k \gamma_j x_j + \varepsilon_t
$$

where the $x_j$ are possible control variables. Given that you chose the appropriate controls, this model estimates the causal effect of las weeks $B$ on the current $A$.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my worry. While I agree with what you said, I'm curious if you might know exactly where the problems lie with my set up? Would my design still give me an unbiased estimate of the lagged effect of B on A while accounting for unobserved confounders, and if not, why is it biased?